# Eric Lengyel, Mathematics, Plucker Coordinates Exercise

Tags: math, geometry, game-development

At the chapter 3 of "Eric Lengyel, Foundations Of Game Engine Development, Volume 1: Mathematics" i can not understand, how to solve exercise 10 ( on the "3.5 Plucker Coordinates" theme).

> "Let {v|m1} and {v|m2} be parallel lines having the same direction but different moments. Find a formula for the distance *d* between theese two lines by considering the triangle formed by the origin and the closest point to the origin on each line"

It seemed simple to me at first, but after many attempts I can't figure out where to start. I've tried different ways, but couldn't get the right answer:

> d = (| (v x (m2 - m1) |) / (sqr(v))

maybe someone know, what's the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a mathematical question, not a programming question?

Comment: @njuffa, rather you are right, but i can't get an answer about 2 weeks, so decided to try here. May be i don't know forums, where i can get an answer for this problem. Perhaps someone while studying opengl or directx faced such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table in that chapter (line G) shows "homogeneous point closest to the origin" as

```
p = (v x m) / v^2
```

Difference between such points for two lines with `m1` and `m2` moments is  vector

```
diff =  p1-p2 = (v x m1) / v^2 -  (v x m2) / v^2 =  (v x (m1-m2)) / v^2
```

Length of this vector is needed distance, because `Op1` and `Op2` vectors are perpendicular to direction `v`, points `O`, `p1` and `p2` belongs to a plane, perpendicular to lines, and `diff=p1-p2` belonging that plane is perpendicular to the lines too, hence it's length is the distance between lines.

P.S. `Op1p2` is triangle mentioned in the problem statement

P.P.S

Point p lies on Pluecker line if

```
p x v = m
```

multiply both parts by v

```
v x (p x v) = v x m
```

transform the left part by [Lagrange identity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

```
p * (v.dot.v) - v * (p.dot.v) = p * v^2 
(because (p.dot.v)== 0 for perpendicular to the line) 
p * v^2 = v x m
p = (v x m) / v^2
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you explain, how we get v^2 in the denominator? if we get G as base:
p = ((v x m) | v^2) - where v^2 is the *w* parameter of 4 component vector p, it is not the denominator value.
And also, another one moment not so clear to me: we know, that [p2-p1] is vector, but the length of this vector is calculated by other methods, isn't it?

Comment: Length of vector [p2-p1] is calculated by standard method (sqrt(sum of components squared))

Comment: Added possible G deduction

Comment: i've got. Thanks a lot!